# difference between two pandas dataframe indexes throws error

Tags: pandas

The code I am trying to troubleshoot, does a difference between two dataframes and throws this error. The exception is

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I then tried to replicate this with the following code. It works fine.

```
dummy_data1 = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'Feature1': ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I'],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'J'],
        'dates': ['12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'dates'])


dummy_data2 = {
        'id': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        'Feature1': [0.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0],
        'Feature2': ['B', 'D', 'F', 'J'],
        'dates': ['12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020','12/12/2020']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2', 'dates'])

df1.index.difference(df2.index).tolist()
```

I dont even know how to replicate this issue. I thought it is because there are data type diffferences between columns. Any tips on troubleshooting this would be helpful.

Comment: This code ran without error for me.  Even if I set the index as 'id', no errors.

Comment: @ScottBoston, I know. The error happens in some other code. This is code I tried to replicate

Comment: Try pasting the full trace stack also.